# React avoid lowercase conversion on null objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that I filter before displaying it in a table.  
Before filtering, the values are converted to lowercase. However, this obviously fails when the object in question is null. How can I adapt this function to make it work with null values?

```
function onSearchText(text, props) {
    let filtered;
    let searchText;
    if (text) {
        searchText = text.toLowerCase();
        filtered = props.users.filter((user) =>
            user.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            user.jobTitle.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            user.department.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            user.phoneNumber1.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        );
    } else {
        filtered = props.users;
    }
    setUsers(filtered);    
}
```

Cheers,
CJ

Comment: You can filter more than once? Add another before it, this time removing the null values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, since you are not mutating your variables, there is no need to declare them or make them mutable, so you can shorten the function like this:

```
function onSearchText(text, props) { 
    if (text) {
        const searchText = text.toLowerCase();
        const filtered = props.users.filter((user) =>
            user.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            user.jobTitle.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            user.department.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            user.phoneNumber1.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        setUsers(filtered)
        );
    } else {
        setUsers(props.users);
    }   
}
```

Then, if the user object may have empty values, you should be able to use optional chaining on the user object like this:

```
function onSearchText(text, props) {
    if (text) {
        const searchText = text.toLowerCase();
        const filtered = props.users.filter((user) =>
            user.fullName?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            user.jobTitle?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            user.department?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            user.phoneNumber1?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        setUsers(filtered)
        );
    } else {
        setUsers(props.users);
    }
}
```

Which would only attempt the conversion if `user.[key]` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

you add a condition of object if it is null than do nothing otherwise do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

While there are so many ways to achieve this, you can simply do the below.

```
filtered = props.users.filter((user) =>
            (user.fullName || '').toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            (user.jobTitle || '').toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            (user.department || '').toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
            (user.phoneNumber1 || '').toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        );
```

It is better to have a null check for `props.users` as well.